# The spectrum of a bounded linear operator on a $X=C[0;1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, spectral-theory

I am working with the book "Introductory Functional Analysis With Applications", written by Kreyzig and I got the trouble with problem 1 and problem 2 in section 7.3, which are:

**Problem 1:**

"Let $X=C[0;1]$ and define $T: X \rightarrow X$ by $Tx=vx$, where $v \in X$ is fixed. Find $\sigma (T)$. Note that $\sigma (T)$ is closed.
"

**Problem 2:**

"Find a linear operator $T: C[0;1] \rightarrow C[0;1]$ whose spectrum is a given interval $[a,b]$."

There is a hint for problem 1 that $\sigma (T)$ is the range of $v$. However, I have no idea of proving this.

Could you please help me to explain those problems in detail?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\lambda = v(t_0)$ for some $t_0\in [0,1]$, then $(T-\lambda I)x$ vanishes at $t_0$ for every $x\in C[0,1]$, which proves that $T-\lambda I$ is not surjective if $\lambda$ is in the range of $v$. So the range of $v$ is contained in the spectrum of $T$. If $\lambda$ is not in the range of $v$, then $\inf_{t\in [0,1]}|\lambda-v(t)| = \epsilon > 0$ because the range is compact, which gives the continuous invertibility of multiplication by $T-\lambda I$:
$$
            (T-\lambda I)^{-1}x = \frac{1}{v-\lambda}x.
$$
So $\sigma(T)=\{ v(t) : t \in [0,1] \}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: I have a doubt, in your test you use that $\lambda$ belongs to the spectrum of $T$ since $T-\lambda I$ is not surjective, but it should not be analyzed in $(T-\lambda I): X\to( T-\lambda I) (X)$?, which of course it is already surjective.

Comment: @Sofia : If $\lambda =v(t_0)$ for some $t_0\in[0,1]$, then every $f \in (T-\lambda I)C[0,1]$ vanishes at $t_0$, which is proof that $(T-\lambda I)$ is not surjective.